# htaccess and rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i am trying to rewrite an url.
I need only this rule, when the url is:

```
mysite.com/news/WHATEVER
```

the request have to be handled by:

```
mysite.com/news.php
```

the page will then process the url in someway, i believe that if it become

```
mysite.com/news.php?name=whatever
```

it's better.

I think it's a simple rule to be implemented, but I think I don't know how. I tried to read some .htaccess guides and such but I could not figure it.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I found that

```
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)$ /news.php?name=$1
```

is working